# How do I change gmail accounts when using the share functionality of an app?

Tags: gmail

I have 3 gmail accounts coming into my gmail app.  I also frequently use the "Share" feature of many apps (Browser, Gallery, BeyondPod...) to share links via gmail however when it opens up the email compose screen sometimes I am given a dropdown to choose which account to send it from and other times it defaults to the account of the last inbox I checked and doesn't give me an option to change it.

This does not seem to have any rhyme or reason to it. Does anyone know how I can make sure to always have the option to choose which account I'm sending from?

Comment: Hello? Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: **HELLO...** HELLO... hello... [/echo]  <? php include $tumbleweed ?>

Comment: Is it an issue with a particular app? For the apps that give you a dropdown menu, does it at least consistently provide the dropdown?

Comment: Well, it is particularly with the Gmail App.  When ever I choose to share something via gmail from my browswer or gallery or music player... it pops up Gmail, however sometimes it defaults to the last gmail account I used as the "From Address" sometimes it gives me a choice.  No, it doesn't consistently provide a dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this is fixed in the latest Gmail App which you should be able to download from the Market.

(This used to bug the hell out of me - sometimes the drop down would work, other times not, completely at random. Haven't had the issue since the last Gmail App update)

Comment: Thanks!  It seems to work now.  I'll have to give it a couple days to make sure it's fixed for good.

Comment: @Matt I'm genuinely pleased for you! I use this feature a *lot* and it really drove me crazy, especially as it was so random :)